# Cordova - Access device functionality from remote HTML

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova

I have a Cordova application that waits for the `deviceready` event and, when that event fires, sets the `window.location.href` to a remote site, say, `http://foo.bar.com/lander.html`. From that page, I have several links to other pages - say `page1.html` and `page2.html`. I want to put a button in `page1.html` that calls Cordova's `navigator.notification.vibrate` function.

I have the above set up and everything appears to work, except that `navigation.notification` is undefined when I click the button in `page1.html` to try to get the device to vibrate. I have copied `cordova.js` onto `foo.bar.com` and am referencing it from `page1.html`. Do I have to include other javascript source files on `foo.bar.com`? Will this approach ever work?

Would it work if instead of changing the window location I were to get the content by AJAX and put the content in a div container in the `index.html` page that underlies the Cordova app?

This is all on iOS if that matters. I included the `dialogs` and `vibration` plugins only. I am receiving the `deviceready` event in the Cordova app and successfully redirecting to the remote site. Please let me know if there are other factors which I need to take into consideration. Thanks.

UPDATE 1: I got vibration working from the Cordova app's local index.html by using navigator.vibrate instead of navigator.notification.vibrate. Changing this on the remote site did not help. I also tried including copies of vibration.js, Cordova.js and cordova_plugins.js from the remote page - still no luck.

UPDATE 2: I found in the Cordova docs where what I'm asking about is discussed: Invoking Cordova JavaScript functions from a remotely-loaded HTML page (an HTML page not stored locally on the device) is an unsupported configuration. This is because Cordova was not designed for this, and the Apache Cordova community does no testing of this configuration. While it can work in some circumstances, it is not recommended nor supported. There are challenges with the same origin policy, keeping the JavaScript and native portions of Cordova synchronized at the same version (since they are coupled via private APIs which may change), the trustworthiness of remote content calling native local functions, and potential app store rejection.

The display of remotely-loaded HTML content in a webview should be done using Cordova's InAppBrowser. The InAppBrowser is designed so that JavaScript running there does not have access to the Cordova JavaScript APIs for the reasons listed above. Please refer to the Security Guide.

Based on this, it sounds possible but like we'd be out on our own. Still, if anybody is successfully doing this, we'd like to give it a try.

Comment: As you said, it's an unsupported configuration an not recommended. Anyway, if you upload the whole platforms/ios/www folder to a server it should work

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same thing, but no luck so far. Is it still unsupported and the only "good" choice is to bundle the whole application if I want to access native features?

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik We eventually got something working by dynamically requesting JS from the server at runtime. If I recall, it involved some trick with adding script elements to the page and something to do with an IMG tag. YMMV.

Comment: @Patrick87 Thanks a lot for the trick, I might try doing something similar actually. I did not think of this solution, but all my app is an angular file, so I can just as easy get it directly from the app, while technically the `app` itself will stay local on the device, and whole app would be just `index.html`. Thanks a lot for help, it's actually should be an answer that I'll upvote. Otherwise it's possible to do an app that auto-upates itself, but it's too complicated for my task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thinhk what you are looking for is a push notification. There is a plugin for this. 
http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/
You need a task running on your app though.

Hope this is helpfull.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm not sure this is what we're going for.